# Why do I get different results with Get-WinEvent versus Get-EventLog?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, event-log, get-eventlog

I'm trying to use `Get-WinEvent` to retrieve events from the eventlog for specific provider names that my company uses to write to the eventlog. I'm finding that I'm getting differing results depending on whether I use `Get-WinEvent` versus `Get-EventLog`, and I'm not sure why.

Using this test code (both provider names are proprietary names for different applications my company has):

```bsh
$pName1 = "MagicFS6"
$pName2 = "MT_WPLAppServer"
$provider = $pName2

$fhash = @{
    logname      = 'application';
    providername = $provider;
    StartTime    = '8/1/2017 12:00:00 AM'
}
$fhashevent = $null
$fhashevent = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $fhash
$count = $fhashevent.Count
Write-Host "$provider had $count events using Get-WinEvent"

$eventlog = Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source $provider -After '8/1/2017 12:00:00 AM'
$count = $eventlog.Count
Write-Host "$provider had $count events using Get-EventLog"
```

Running with `$pName1` (MagicFS6), both `Get-WinEvent` and `Get-EventLog` return the same number of events. This tells me that the code is equivalent.

However, running with `$pName2` (MT_WPLAppServer), `Get-WinEvent` returns 0 events, and `Get-EventLog` correctly returns thousands of results.

[image: Results image]

> MagicFS6 had 12662 events using Get-WinEvent
>   MagicFS6 had 12662 events using Get-EventLog
>
> MT_WPLAppServer had 0 events using Get-WinEvent
>   MT_WPLAppServer had 11483 events using Get-EventLog

For my needs, I need to use `Get-WinEvent`, so I would love some ideas on why this is not returning reliable results.